# Md-chips email validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Md-chips email validation

How to create an email validation for md-chips? My expression below is not working, since, the ng-keypress directive is called whenever I type something.

Suggestions?

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" ng-cloak="">
     <md-context class="md-padding">
       <md-chips md-separator-keys="ctrl.customKeys" ng-keypress="ctrl.validateEmail()" ng-model="ctrl.ConfiguracaoRegra.Emails" md-max-chips="20" placeholder="Inserir um email..." ng-required="true" type="email"></md-chips>
       </md-context>
   </div>
 </div>

   vm.validateEmail = function (keyEvent) {
    var emailValue = angular.element(".md-input").val();
    var reg = /^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
    if (reg.test(emailValue)) {
        vm.isEmailValid = true;
    } else {
        vm.isEmailValid = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: "the ng-keypress directive is called whenever I type something" - when do you want it to be validated then?

Comment: @John Whenever I create a chips

Comment: I can't remember how md-chips works, but couldn't you validate when the user presses the enter key?

Comment: Okay, I'll be altering my expression.

Comment: This, I want to validate whenever the user presses enter

Comment: You should have a look at this https://angular.io/guide/form-validation and this for a live example https://stackblitz.com/angular/bxvldvkjeav. Also you can use timeout function until the method is fired.

Comment: My solution was: create a javascript function where I evaluate whether the ENTER was entered and use a regular expression ('/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0 (9)] + (\. [A-z0-9 -] +) * (\. [Az] {2,4}) $ / '), validating by the test () method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was: create a javascript function where I evaluate whether the ENTER was entered and use a regular expression ('/^[_a-z0-9]+(.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0 (9)] + (. [A-z0-9 -] +) * (. [Az] {2,4}) $ / '), validating by the test () method.

```js
  function validateEmail(x) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                var emailValue = x;
                var reg = /^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
                if (!reg.test(emailValue)) {                                        
                    toastr.error("Digite um email válido!");                    
                    vm.ConfiguracaoRegra.Emails.pop();
                }
            };

    };
```

```html
<md-chips md-on-add="ctrl.validateEmail($chip)" ng-model="ctrl.ConfiguracaoRegra.Emails" md-max-chips="20" placeholder="Inserir um email..." type="email" required></md-chips>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shuold use `ng-change` directive instead of `ng-keypress`, or combine both `md-on-add` and `md-on-remove` (see https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3580#issuecomment-347052946)